# What exactly are knots (b-spline)

Tags: c++, spline

Knots are the things that make the curve continuous, like in Bezier curves, the line segment from the mid point control point have to have the same tangent and length and if they are then the Bezier curves are c-continuous.

So, knots as I have read are parameters of the spline that handle the start and end points hence the c-continuosity of the curve.

So, what would a knot data type look like ?

Any idea's?

Answer (score 4):

A B-spline is a piecewise polynomial, and its knots are the points where the pieces meet.  A knot would have the same type as the argument to the polynomials.  Generally you would also supply a value at each knot, and either a control point between each consecutive pair or a first derivative.  As you say, smoothness depends on the function and its derivatives being continuous at the knots.

Comment: Then surely, if the knots specify the start and end points of a curve segment then knots are control points also. And if the notation for a knot vector is (0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2) then that would equate to : the first three zeros defining the first knot the start point, the second three to the second point the end point and start point the next three to the end point of the second, although I am still confused . . .

Comment: Yes.  Here’s a more formal presentation: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html. But, intuitively, what’s going on is that you’re dividing the line segment [0,1] into pieces at points called knots.  As you move along the interval from *t* = 0 to *t* = 1, you pass each of these knots.  The closer you get to each knot, the closer you move to its associated control point, and you’re affected by only the closest control points. In a clamped spline, you’ll end up hitting every second control point, while the others just determine the path you take between them.